# Javascript generated textbox value = undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all, let me note that although my JavaScript is fairly long, I believe all of the modifications needed to fix my code will probably be in the (document).ready function. The problem I'm running into is that when I generate a textbox (.wy) in JavaScript by switching the items on menu 2 and enter a value, it returns undefined when I click the calculate button. However, I am able to get my HTML-generated textbox (.amount) value without any problems. How do I fix this?

```
HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="salaryconverter2.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="salaryconverter2.js"></script>
    <title>Salary Converter 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Salary Converter</h1>
    <div class="1"></div>
    <div class="2"></div>
    <select id="menu1" onchange="switch1()">
        <option class='men1'>hourly wage</option>
        <option class='men1'>weekly earnings</option>
        <option class='men1'>monthly salary</option>
        <option class='men1'>annual salary</option>
    </select>
    <div>to</div>
    <select id="menu2" onchange="switch2()">
        <option>hourly wage</option>
        <option>weekly earnings</option>
        <option>monthly salary</option>
        <option>annual salary</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    $<textarea class="amount" placeholder="Enter amount"></textarea>per
    <div class="per1">hour</div>
    <div class="anchor1">y</div>
    <div class="anchor2">z</div>
    <button id="button">Calculate</button>
    <div class="result">x</div>
</body>
</html>

and Javascript:

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu1').on("menuselect", function (event, ui) {
        var value1 = $("#menu1 option:selected").text();
        var value2 = $("#menu2 option:selected").text();
    });
    value1 = "hourly wage";
    value2 = "hourly wage";

    $("#menu1").change(function() {
        //ifStatement;
    });
    $("#menu2").change(function() {
        //ifStatement;
        $(".anchor1").html("<textarea id='w/y' placeholder='(52) weeks per year'></textarea>");
    });
    $("#button").click(function() {
        console.log($(".wy").val());
        console.log($(".amount").val());
        //conversion();
    });
});



function ifStatements() {
    console.log("D");
    switch1();
    switch2();
    if (value1 == "hourly wage") {
        $(".per1").html("hour");
    }
    if (value1 == "weekly earnings") {
        $(".per1").html("week");
    }
    if (value1 == "monthly salary") {
        $(".per1").html("month");
    }
    if (value1 == "annual salary") {
        $(".per1").html("year");
    }

    if (((value1 == "weekly earnings") && (value2 == "annual salary")) || ((value2 == "weekly earnings") && (value1 == "annual salary"))) {
        console.log("x");
        $(".anchor1").html("<textarea id='wy' placeholder='(52) weeks per year'></textarea>");
        $(".anchor2").html("");
    }
    else if (((value1 == "weekly earnings") && (value2 == "monthly salary")) || ((value2 == "weekly earnings") && (value1 == "monthly salary"))) {
        $(".anchor1").html("<textarea placeholder='(4) weeks per month'></textarea>");
        $(".anchor2").html("");
    }
    else if (((value1 == "hourly wage") && (value2 == "annual salary")) || ((value2 == "hourly wage") && (value1 == "annual salary"))) {
        $(".anchor1").html("<textarea placeholder='(40) hours per week'></textarea>");
        $(".anchor2").html("<textarea placeholder='(52) weeks per year'></textarea>");
    }
    else if (((value1 == "hourly wage") && (value2 == "monthly salary")) || ((value2 == "hourly wage") && (value1 == "monthly salary"))) {
        $(".anchor1").html("<textarea placeholder='(40) hours per week'></textarea>");
        $(".anchor2").html("<textarea placeholder='(4) weeks per month'></textarea>");
    }
    else if (((value1 == "hourly wage") && (value2 == "weekly earnings")) || ((value2 == "hourly wage") && (value1 == "weekly earnings"))) {
        $(".anchor1").html("<textarea placeholder='(40) hours per week'></textarea>");
        $(".anchor2").html("");
    }
    else if (((value1 == "annual salary") && (value2 == "monthly salary")) || ((value2 == "annual salary") && (value1 == "monthly salary"))) {
        $(".anchor1").html("<textarea placeholder='(12) months per year'></textarea>");
        $(".anchor2").html("");
    }
    else {
        $(".anchor1").html("");
        $(".anchor2").html("");
    }
}
function conversion() {
    console.log($("input#w/y").val());
}

function switch1() {
        value1 = $("#menu1 option:selected").text();;
    }
function switch2() {
        value2 = $("#menu2 option:selected").text();
    }
```

Comment: just post some of the relevant code pls

Comment: Could you construct a simpler version of the code that replicates the issue you are experiencing? Perhaps a JSFiddle? This is a lot of code to parse, and if you provided a simpler example, it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$(".wy").val()
```

To

```
$("#wy").val()
```

You have set the id of the textarea and not its class to "wy".

Answer (score 0):

On the line below, you're creating a textarea with id `wy`:

```
$(".anchor1").html("<textarea id='wy' ............
```

Yet you try to access it using the class selector `.wy`. Change to the ID selector `#wy`:

```
console.log($("#wy").val());
```